# How to change background to white in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, desktop-customization, color-theme

I need to place a custom image in desktop background in windows 10. I have placed it centered, but because the image is smaller than the screen, the rest of it is filled with black color.

I tried to customize the colors in order to set white background, but configuration only allows me to set either a desktop image or a solid color, but not both simultaneously.

How can I do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Windows does not natively allow you to do this as far as I know.

But there is an easy alternative.

Open the image in any image editor. Increase the image to the resolution of your monitor, but don't resize the image itself. Now you can color the remaining of the background to your liking, including white.

Save the image, and set the new image as your background.

You can even decide to combine multiple images to one image if you want more of a background.

Comment: really? It is strange that Windows 10 does not allow that, if even windows 7 does.

Comment: It isn't. There are many things that Microsoft removed from windows 10 that worked in earlier versions. For example, the creators update even removed the control panel shortcut from the WIN+X menu, and most of the control panel options have been migrated to the new settings menu. Unfortunately many settings are lost because of it. This one included.

Comment: I guess your solution is a joke. What if the screen size changes? I need to make a new image? A common scenario is: Connecting an external monitor or even a TV to the notebook. What will happen there? Black background will still apears

Comment: I'm sorry, my solution was not meant as a joke. But the only thing I can think of that may make this work, is by using the Windows 10 High-Contrast theme. That should allow you to edit the background color. As for resolution changes etc, yes that would indeed require you to make a new image, or settle for the stretch setting, so the image gets stretched.